# International Time Zones Are Wrong in Clock App

Tags: clock, time-zones

Since Android's integrated Clock app does not offer to select time zones, I decided to find location reflecting time zones I need - EST, CST and MST

For EST (-5 UTC ) I chose Tampa but for CST (-6 UTC) I wanted to choose Washington DC but it has EST (-5 UTC) time zone, which is wrong. For MST (-7 UTC) I wanted to choose Las Vegas because Nevada was not on the list but Las Vegas has PST (-8 UTC) time zone which is wrong.

Comment: Are they all off by one? If so, its DST and they are right.

Comment: Daylight Saving Time ended on Sunday, November 6 in US

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is. I think you are reporting errors in the Time Zone data in your copy of the Android system.

You report that Android lists Washington DC as EST (-5 UTC), and say that this is wrong. According to a [Time Zone database entry for Washington DC](http://www.convertit.com/Go/ConvertIt/World_Time/Current_Time.ASP?For=Washington+District+of+Columbia+United+States), based on the [IANA Time Zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), this city does indeed observe U.S. Eastern Time, so -5 UTC is correct during the Easter Standard Time part of the year.

You report that Android lists Las Vegas as PST (-8 UTC), and say that this is wrong. According to the [Time Zone database entry for Las Vegas](http://www.convertit.com/Go/ConvertIt/World_Time/Current_Time.ASP?For=Las+Vegas+Nevada+United+States) at that same site, this city does indeed observe U.S. Pacific Time, so -8 UTC is correct during the Easter Standard Time part of the year.

So, I think this evidence does not prove Android's data to be incorrect.

For CST, a good major city is Chicago, Illinois. For MST, a good major city is Denver, Colorado.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe TimeZone Changer will help? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.futurek.android.tzc